# Is Terragrunt available for Azure?

Tags: azure, terraform, terragrunt

I want to manage multiple environments with difference in instance size  and instance cost. Can we use  Terragrunt used for that purpose. Also is Terragrunt used in Azure?

Comment: Why would you think it isn't? And why do you think you need Terragrunt for that instead of just using Terraform as is?

Comment: We want a scenario where we would have multiple directory (i.e. Prod, QA and Stage) in main directory and main directory would have main file which would have choice to select if prod then the prod directory code should get executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Terragrunt is just a wrapper for Terraform script, not related to the actual provider. Terragrunt worked better for Terraform < 0.12 but now I would not recommend it.

For handling multiple environments you can:

- Use Terraform Workspaces (available for Azure backend)
- Use a smart layout of directories and modules. [Check here](https://dev.to/piotrgwiazda/main-module-approach-for-handling-multiple-environments-in-terraform-1oln) - with Azure example.

Comment: Any reason for your suggestion? We are moving from Terraform Workspaces to Terragrunt because it is much simpler. Also why should Terragrunt work not as good with Terraform 0.12, 0.13 and newer?

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is available. You have [this nice article](https://medium.com/@tsuyoshiushio/terragrunt-quick-start-with-azure-4a9a09ab2e21) explaining how to use it on Azure. But, i would not recommend you to go in that direction. Most of the Terragrunt features have been adopted by Terraform Enterprise. Terragrunt allows you to work faster than Terraform for some cases but it has the main issues than Terraform. In my opinion, the main benefits are the plan-all/apply-all command if you have a lot of different sub-resources grouped by folders, but you can work on and achieve the same with Terraform.